# Is there equivalent of Ruby Enumerable#one? Enumerable#none? in Elixir?

Tags: enums, elixir

How to implement `one?` and `none?` in Elixir in efficient way?

What do you think about this one?

```
defmodule MyEnum do
  def one?(enum, fun) do
    Enum.count(enum, fun) == 1 && true || false
  end

  def none?(enum, fun) do
    Enum.count(enum, fun) == 0 && true || false
  end
end
```

Usage examples:

```
iex(6)> MyEnum.none?([0,0,0,0], fn(x) -> x == 1 end)
true
iex(7)> MyEnum.none?([0,0,1,0], fn(x) -> x == 1 end)
false
iex(8)> MyEnum.none?([0,1,1,0], fn(x) -> x == 1 end)
false
iex(9)> MyEnum.one?([0,1,1,0], fn(x) -> x == 1 end)
false
iex(10)> MyEnum.one?([0,1,0,0], fn(x) -> x == 1 end)
true
iex(11)> MyEnum.one?([0,0,0,0], fn(x) -> x == 1 end)
false
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd use `Stream.filter` and `Enum.take(2)` to implement `one?`. This will make sure that only at most 2 elements that match `fun` are traversed while your `Enum.count` solution will traverse through the whole enum.

For `none?`, you can just return `!Enum.any?(...)`.

```
defmodule MyEnum do
  def one?(enum, fun) do
    case enum |> Stream.filter(fun) |> Enum.take(2) do
      [_] -> true
      _ -> false
    end
  end

  def none?(enum, fun) do
    !Enum.any?(enum, fun)
  end
end

IO.inspect MyEnum.none?([0,0,0,0], fn(x) -> x == 1 end)
IO.inspect MyEnum.none?([0,0,1,0], fn(x) -> x == 1 end)
IO.inspect MyEnum.none?([0,1,1,0], fn(x) -> x == 1 end)
IO.inspect MyEnum.one?([0,1,1,0], fn(x) -> x == 1 end)
IO.inspect MyEnum.one?([0,1,0,0], fn(x) -> x == 1 end)
IO.inspect MyEnum.one?([0,0,0,0], fn(x) -> x == 1 end)
```

Output:

```
true
false
false
false
true
false
```

Comment: `Stream.filter |> Enum.take(2)` is _very, very_ elegant.

Comment: `Enum.none?` should exists. :( just as `unless`, `Enum.reject` do along with `if` and `Enum.filter`...

Answer (score 2):

[`Enum`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html) module already has [`Enum.all?/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#all?/2) and [`Enum.any?/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#any?/2), as Dogbert said (I put it here for reference links.)

Also, here is an exotic way for `one?` that has definitely much worse performance, than `Enum.take(2)`, but is still funny (using comprehension):

```
"*" == for elem <- [0,1,1,0], fn e -> e == 1 end.(elem), into: "", do: "*"
```

Comment: Between you and@dogbert there is a lot of good Elixir info getting propagated! Thanks guys!

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci I was in doubt whether I should post this as an answer, now I am not. Thank you for the warm words.